# Space around in xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Im using xamarin forms.

i wanna design my xaml files but i realized something strange.

left and right of entry has space that i couldnt remove even with custom renderer.

is there any idea what is might be?
i tried padding,margin,HorizontalOption none of them effected.

even i tried to setPadding to 0 from custom renderer in android but it didnt work.

the first one is label as you can see filled out all the space but entry has an space around it .

[image: Picture]

**Update:**

this is my xaml codes and im using android emulator to test.

```
<StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Spacing="15">

        <Label Text="fds" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
        <Entry BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

    </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the Xaml code you are trying?

Comment: Check if your parent of that Entry has padding set? Also post your xaml here so we can help you out. Otherwise we cant do anything.

Comment: Agree with Bruno, please post the xaml code for this, then i could make a test for you, your screenshot seems come from XAML Designer, did you run your code in Android Simulator?

Comment: We need some `XAML` code to actually help you out brother

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro I've added some xaml codes.

Comment: @Woj I've added some xaml codes.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I've added some xaml codes.

Comment: @G.hakim I've added some xaml codes.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @mohammadkamali Remove Spacing="15".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that entry has Default margin value. so i set it to 0 and everything worked.

here is my code

```
<StackLayout>
            <Entry Margin="0" Text="fd" BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            <Label Text="fd" BackgroundColor="Red" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

don't know how is your implementation but this what I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns:bases="clr-namespace:WhiteSolution.Views.Bases"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                       xmlns:viewModelBase="clr-namespace:WhiteSolution.ViewModels.Bases"
                       viewModelBase:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
                       x:Class="WhiteSolution.Views.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
              BackgroundColor="WhiteSmoke">

            <StackLayout Padding="0"
                         Spacing="0"
                         BackgroundColor="Blue">
                <Label Text="no space label"
                       Margin="0"                       
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                       FontSize="Large"/>
                <Entry Text="no space entry" 
                       Margin="0"
                       BackgroundColor="Red"
                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="Large"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </Grid>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

and i get this result [image]
if you share your code it will be more useful

Comment: It is really needed the tag <ContentPage.Content> or it could be removed? I think you can put the <Grid> directly on the <ContentPage> block, don't see the difference

Comment: no, it's not needed just naming convention

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Padding Property should be 0 in main StackLayout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="SampleApp.Views.DashboardView">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="0" BindingContext="{Binding Dashboard}">

        <!-- Controls -->

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```